# Global Variable Scope in python

Tags: python, types, scope, global-variables, variable-assignment

Should I need to Global everything Global? Considering scope?

I keep randomly running into this problem, Im gonna assume its some how a syntax problem on myside. But variables out side of a scope in python seems to be inconsistent... my situation is

```
libFound=False

def Setup():
   _setup_import()
   print('booting:',libFound)
   #--Here I get False?
   if libFound:
      _boot()
   else:print('Did not Boot')

def _setup_import():
   sys.path.append(PATH)
try:
   import libwrapper
   global libwrapper
except:
   #Critical Exception
else:
   #found
   libFound=True
   print(libFound)#--Here I get True
```

I assume this is garbage collection but I would think it would match gloval before local variables, should I have to global everything global? Scope is scope, I seem to get this often in python. I would like to include it seems to happen most when initiateing with None or it being Bool

Makeing variables global,checking syntax, I've tried researching this but I don't understand if its my syntax possibly or my lack or understanding of how python is actually handleing variable

Comment: `Should I need to Global everything Global?` - no, only what you update.

Comment: If you set a variable to True, and then immediately print it, why would you expect any result other than True?

Comment: And what do you mean by `Here I get False`? That function is never called (at least not in the code that you've posted).

Comment: Also, I have no idea what question you are actually asking.  If you're getting unexpected results from this code, **then say so**.

Comment: `libFound` is the global you are trying to modify, but you never used `global libFound` to declare the name as a global variable.

Comment: A global variable is, by definition, bound in the global scope. But assignments to names in a function always define a new local variable, unless you declare the name as global or non-local using `global` or `nonlocal`, respectively.

Comment: @JohnGordon because latter its returning false, a diffrent result so I want it to prove to me its assigning, your right in that I probably could have put it up one in the scope and it would be more acurate

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb because the setup lib function is supossed to set libFound to true

Comment: @cheoner just tried it with global, same results

Comment: What is "the setup lib function"? I see `#--Here I get False?` inside function `Setup`, but that function is never called anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

A global variable is, by definition, bound in the global scope. But assignments to names in a function always define a new local variable, unless you declare the name as global or non-local using global or nonlocal, respectively. –
chepner
10 mins ago
Boom... inside the scope of _setup_libraries() I made it global and it worked, like you said inside the scope of the method it was local

Comment: Is that an answer to your on question? It sure doesn't look like one.

Comment: The question was why is my variable at the top of my script not global. The answer is because the method was makeing its own local, I had to tell it it was global...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the garbage collector.
I think you may misunderstand how scoping works in python.

See code & comments in it below. I hope it helps.

```
myGlobal = False

def ask_global():
    # To use Glboal Variable, we dont need to use global keyword
    print(myGlobal)

def toggle_global():
    # Changes the value of the global variable
    global myGlobal
    myGlobal = not myGlobal

def global_false():
    # Will not actually set myGlobal false, because scoping
    # When assigning a global without first declaring it as global, 
    # it will be a new local variable
    # myGlobal = not myGlobal
    # would result in 'myGlobal' referenced before assignment
    myGlobal = False
    

print(myGlobal) # False
ask_global() # False
if True:
    # We're in global scope here, changing the global variable
    myGlobal = True

print(myGlobal) # True
ask_global() # True

global_false()
print(myGlobal) # True
ask_global() # True

toggle_global()
print(myGlobal) # False
ask_global() # False
```